# Прошу помочь найти ошибку в типе данных str и int

Tags: python

```
print("Tere see on SkyNet programm")
print("Kui te tahate saata terminator T-1000 aastasse 1995, sisestage'Jah'")
print("Palun, ära proovige sisestada 'Ei', või midagi veel")

jah = ""
jah == "Jah" == "JAH" == "jah"
katsesid = 3

while jah != "Jah" and katsesid > 0:
    katsesid = katsesid - 1
    print("SkyNet palub sind, teil on jäänud" + katsesid + "veel")

    jah = input()

    if jah == "jah":
        print("Aitah, et aidasite meile apokalüpsuse tegemises")
    else:
        print("See saab negatiivselt teile effektida")
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос более конкретное объяснение чего вы хотите и ошибку. Так больше шансов получить корректный ответ

Comment: Замените `print("SkyNet palub sind, teil on jäänud" + katsesid + "veel")` на `print(f"SkyNet palub sind, teil on jäänud {katsesid} veel")`

Comment: Строчку `jah == итд` перед katsesid=3 можно и нужно выкинуть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
print("Tere see on SkyNet programm")
print("Kui te tahate saata terminator T-1000 aastasse 1995, sisestage'Jah'")
print("Palun, ära proovige sisestada 'Ei', või midagi veel")

jah = ""
jah == "Jah" == "JAH" == "jah"
katsesid = 3

while jah != "Jah" and katsesid > 0:
    katsesid = katsesid - 1
    print("SkyNet palub sind, teil on jäänud" + str(katsesid) + "veel")

    jah = input()

    if jah == "jah":
        print("Aitah, et aidasite meile apokalüpsuse tegemises")
    else:
        print("See saab negatiivselt teile effektida")
```